# Puppet Exec tag onlyif troubles

Tags: bash, puppet

I have this bit of code:

```
if ($galera_master == $::fqdn) {
    if ( $vendor_type == 'GoofyIT' ) {
        $onlyif = [
            "ps -ef | grep mysqld_safe | grep wsrep-new-cluster > /dev/null",
            "test $desired_cluster_size == $(mysql --defaults-file=/root/.my.cnf -e \"SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_size'\" | grep wsrep_cluster_size | awk '{print \$2}') > /dev/null",
        ]
        $unless = [ "test $desired_cluster_size -lt $(/usr/bin/mysql --defaults-file=/root/.my.cnf -e \"SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_size'\" | grep wsrep_cluster_size | awk '{print \$2}')",
                    "ps -ef | grep mysqld_safe | grep wsrep-new-cluster && false",
        ]
        Exec['bootstrap_galera_cluster'] -> Exec['finish_bootstrap']
        exec { 'finish_bootstrap':
            path     => '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin',
            command  => 'pkill -SIGQUIT mysqld; sleep 5; systemctl restart mysqld',
            onlyif   =>  $onlyif,
            #unless   =>  $unless,
        }
    }
}
```

On my node where this bit of code runs I have these conditions:

```
# test 3 -eq $(/usr/bin/mysql --defaults-file=/root/.my.cnf -e "SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_size'" | grep wsrep_cluster_size | awk '{print $2}')
# echo $?
0
# ps -ef | grep mysqld_safe | grep wsrep-new-cluster 
# echo $?
1
```

So I assume when the puppet agent runs on my node I should NOT see `pkill -SIGQUIT mysqld; sleep 5; systemctl restart mysqld` execute. Yet when I run `puppet agent -td` I see that the puppet agent IS executing `pkill -SIGQUIT mysqld; sleep 5; systemctl restart mysqld`.

[The documentation for Exec's onlyif tag](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-onlyif) says this:

**onlyif**

If this parameter is set, then this exec will only run if the command has an exit code of 0. For example:

```
exec { 'logrotate':
  path   => '/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin',
  onlyif => 'test `du /var/log/messages | cut -f1` -gt 100000',
}
```

This would run logrotate only if that test returned true.

Note that this command follows the same rules as the main command, such as which user and group it’s run as. This also means it must be fully qualified if the path is not set.

It also uses the same provider as the main command, so any behavior that differs by provider will match.

Also note that onlyif can take an array as its value, e.g.:

```
onlyif => ['test -f /tmp/file1', 'test -f /tmp/file2'],
```

This will only run the exec if ***all conditions in the array return true***.

Comment: Your `onlyif` and `unless` "commands" are in fact shell pipelines.  If that's what you need then at minimum you should specify `provider => 'shell'`, which is not the default.

Comment: That is a excellent tip! But I found that I needed to do this: `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep mysqld_safe | grep wsrep-new-cluster` instead of `ps -ef | grep mysqld_safe | grep wsrep-new-cluster`.

Comment: It sounds like you've got it sorted.  Well and good.  If I had been confident that the `provider` setting was a complete solution then I'd have made it an answer.

Comment: How would determine what my default provider is? BTW thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: You would determine the default provider by looking at [the provider list for that type in the type reference](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/type.html#exec-providers).  It will be either 'posix' or 'windows', as 'shell' is not the default for anybody.  From context, it seems pretty safe for me to guess 'posix' in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to do this:

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep mysqld_safe | grep wsrep-new-cluster
```

instead of

```
ps -ef | grep mysqld_safe | grep wsrep-new-cluster
```

Comment: Alternatively I like to do something like `ps -ef | grep [m]ysqld_safe | grep [w]srep-new-cluster` as it is slightly cleaner to me. Also consider using `-q` as a cleaner alternative to `> /dev/null`.